# running x11 on cygwin, all terminals stuck at one corner

Tags: cygwin, x11

I am trying to run x11 on cygwin, mainly to run xfig utility, and I am facing a problem.

When I run xinit to start x11, I get a big popup window with one terminal open. But I am unable to open any other terminals in it. To be more specific, when I run "xterm &" in it, a new terminal opens up but it sits on top of the old terminal, and there is no way I can move this window, so the old terminal is as good as useless to me, till I kill the new terminal.

I also tried running "xwin". There a big window popped up, but it does not contain any terminal, and I cant open any terminal, whether by left or right clicking.

I also tried running "startx". A big window opens up but gets killed automatically after a few seconds.

How can I use x11 effectively on cygwin? As of now, I can use with "xinit", but with only one terminal.

Comment: After some amount of googling and experimenting, I found one solution: run "startx /usr/bin/fvwm2". This allows more xterms to be opened with left click. Any other suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The proper mode to start the Xserver on cygwin is to use starxwin.
From its manual:

> The startxwin script is a front end to xinit(1) that provides  a 
>   some what  nicer user interface for running a single session of the X Window
>   System in multiwindow mode.  It is often run with no arguments.

Comment: I tried that. Several lines come up in the cygwin terminal console. But the x window does not pop up. maybe it requires extra settings.

Comment: multiwindow mode just pops up an icon on the taskbar. the window manager uses a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

To move windows around, you need to have a window manager running. You can start this either from the xterm, by passing the name of the window manager as an argument to startx, or by starting it from your X11 startup configuration (memory says that would be ".xinitrc" in your home directory on most unix boxes, but I am not sure if that's true on Windows using Cygwin). The .xinitrc file is "just" a shell-script, with the end of the script indicating "X should shut the server down now" (see example at the end).

There are many possible window managers, including fvwm2 (which according to your comment, you managed to find on your own). A full list of X11 window managers is probably too long to fit in this answer (there are many, there are new ones popping up, and old ones going out of maintenance on an ongoing basis). Some of the not entirely uncommon ones are fvwm2 (already mentioned), cinnamon, twm, ctwm, ratpoison, ... For a more up-to-date list, ask your favourite search engine for "list of X11 window managers".

Example .xinitrc file:

```
# This is an example .xinitrc file, starting first an xterm,
# then a window manager. As the X server terminates when this script
# does, we start the X terminal in the background, but the window
# manager in the foreground, so that "WM exists" signals "X server shuts down"
xterm &
fvwm2
```

Comment: can you suggest how to start from .xinitrc, eg using fvwm2? Also suggest what other window managers can be used. Then I will accept your answer if it works for me.